# Printing on JavaFX8 on OS X produce garbage characters

Tags: printing, javafx-8

I am trying to use the built-in node printing capabilities in JavaFX8 on OS X (Yosemite). I am using the simple code below just to try to print something. But it just produces garbage characters on the printing paper. Any ideas what I am missing?

The printer is configured correctly as I can print other textfiles, PDFs etc. normally.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Printer.getDefaultPrinter().getName());

    VBox v = new VBox();
    v.setPrefSize(200,200);
    Label r1 = new Label("Row 1");
    Label r2 = new Label("Row 2");
    v.getChildren().addAll(r1, r2);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(v));
    primaryStage.show();

    final PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    printerJob.jobStatusProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, status) -> {
        System.out.println(status);
    });

    final boolean b = printerJob.printPage(v);
    if (b)
        printerJob.endJob();

}
```

Comment: This might be relevant https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081707  Titled "JavaFX printing on Mac OS X produces unreadable text output. "

Comment: Thanks for the link and the bug report mentions that it´s fixed in 1.8_60. I am using 1.8.0_74-b02 but still getting the garbled characters.

Comment: No problem.... It seems that this is where the new bug reports go, as they used to use JIRA.  I would try adding to the bug report, or creating your own new report, and seeing what the experts say over there.  They might be able to patch you quickly and get you on your way with a nightly build.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue but later realised that the Javafx does not understand some of the fonts. So had to set the correct fonts on my nodes using css and and then print the node. I suggest please check the fonts that are set on the node that you are trying to print.